# I do not understand the result of returned function

Tags: go

I have following initial code:

```
package main

func test(x int) (func(), func()) {
    return func() {
            println(x)
            x += 10
        }, func() {
            println(x)

        }
}

func main() {
    a, b := test(100)
    a()
    b()
}
```

The output is

```
100
110
```

If I edit the code as follows

```
package main


func test(x int) (func(), func()) {
    return func() {
            println(x)
        }, func() {
            println(x)
            x += 10
        }
}
func main() {
    a, b := test(100)
    a()
    b()
}
```

The result is

```
100
100
```

I expect the last result is following, but it is not, why?

```
110
100
```

Comment: You expect to see an update to a variable that is going to happen but hasn't happened yet? I don't think go supports time-travel just yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` is a func that prints `x`, and `b` is a func that prints `x` and adds 10 to it. If you call `a` first and then `b`, it'll print 100 twice and then add 10 to it, but that will never be printed. Call `b` first and then `a`, and it'll print what you want.